# Clone array with spread operator and add inline

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

With an object I can clone & add like:

```
   let newObject = {
      ...obj,
      [key]: { 
         ...obj[key],
         thing: true }
   }
```

So, this adds some objects to an array, then one object's property is updated.
I know the item's index to update, but don't want to override existing properties.

Now I want to do the same for array:

```
   let newArray = [
     ...arr,
     [key]: { 
         ...arr[key],
         thing: true }
   ]
```

Which might do the same as above.

But that doesn't work.

Should  `{key}:thing` work? I remember reading this somewhere, maybe its ES7?

I could do:

```
   let newArray = arr.map((item, key) => key === index ? { ...item, thing: true } : item);
```

But I was hoping for a cleaner syntax. I'll accept no if there is no similar syntax.

Comment: No, unless you want to append/prepend an item to the array, use `map`. Or array spread with two slices.

Comment: You're confusing arrays and objects.

Comment: `[key]: thing` is not an array element.

Comment: I've updated the examples to clarify

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508) It also looks like you are using the *experimental* spread property, not array spread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const arr = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }, { c: 1 }];
const index = 1;

const newArr = Object.assign([], arr, { [index]: { ...arr[index], thing: true } });
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't have keys, so the syntax you are using doesn't work. Is it an array of objects? If so...

EDIT - based on your comment, try this:

```
// if you know the index of the object you'd like to modify
let newArray = [
     ...arr
]
newArray[idx][key] = thing

// if you don't know the index
let newArray = [
     ...arr
]
newArray.map((el) => {
    if (/* YOUR LOGIC HERE TO DETERMINE IF THIS IS THE OBJECT TO MODIFY! */) {
        return el[key] = thing
    } else {
        return el
    }
})

// if you want it done in one function...
let newArray = []
arr.map((el) => {
    if (el[key]) {
        newArray.push(Object.assign({}, { [key]: thing }))
        return el
    } else {
        newArray.push(Object.assign({}, el))
        return el
    }
})
```

Comment: I need to access a specific object's index in the array, and only update that one's property, after it has been inserted into the new array.

Comment: I'm sure that OP knows that this can be done this way, but I think they're looking for a one-line (i.e. a single expression) solution.

Comment: @TrySpace, I don't think it can be done in one, succinct function. You need to do too many things: 1) copy an arry; 2) check each elem of the array to see if it matches some object you desire; 3) modify the desired elem. The best I can think of is the 3rd example I give in my code, above.